Add an index based on repeated IDs
suppose to have the following:
data DB;
  input ID :$20.;
cards;
0001 
0001 
0002 
0003 
0003 
0004
0004 
0004 
;

and you know IDs are sorted according to a criteria.
Is there a way to get the following?
data DB1;
  input ID :$20. Index;
cards;
0001  1
0001  2
0002  1
0003  1
0003  2
0004  1
0004  2
0004  3
;

In other words I would like to add an incremental numerical index based on the order of each repeated ID (by groups of IDs).
Thank you in advance

This is a great example of the best DATA Step trifecta: by-group processing, first., and a sum statement. This example is one of the best introductions to using it. Here's what the code looks like:
data want;
    set db;
    by id;

    if(first.id) then index=0;

    index+1;
run;

Here's what this does:

When we encounter the first value in a group of IDs, then reset an index variable to 0
Otherwise, for each row, increment an index by 1 and remember its previous value

index+1 is a shortcut for the following code:
data want;
    set have;
    retain index 0;
    index = sum(index,1) ;
run;

The sum statement, index+1, automatically increments a value and retains it going forward. Remember that SAS will reset the value of variables automatically by default with a set statement as it reads each row. Since we don't want to reset our index and keep incrementing it, we can use a sum statement to increment a value indefinitely until we decide to reset it.

Thank you @Stu Sztukowski for help and explanation!
